# copy and paste special with VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code and it keeps giving me an error that the size of the copy area and the paste area are not the same.
but if I just use the copy-paste method, it works perfectly. could you pls help me out.

```
Sub copy()
eRow = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Sheet4.Range("a4", "d23").copy
Sheet5.Cells(eRow, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

Comment: Copy/paste the values one at a time. I would go for a value transfer here although with 2 cells the difference is trivial

Comment: Side note: drop the parentheses around `xlPasteValues`.

Answer (score 0):

Move values one by one with a value transfer. As implied in the name, a value transfer does not carry over formats.

---

**This just copies the 2 individual cells `A4` & `D23`**

```
Sub copy_me()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

ws.Range("A" & lr).Value = ws.Range("A4").Value
ws.Range("D" & lr).Value = ws.Range("D23").Value

End Sub
```

---

**If you meant to grab the entire range `A4:D23` then**

```
ws.Range("A4:D23").Copy
ws.Range("A" & lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

**OR**

```
ws.Range("A" & lr).Resize(20, 4).Value = ws.Range("A4:D23").Value
```

Comment: I think `Range("a4", "d23")` is `A4:D23` - not just the two corner cells.

Comment: I wondered that but the approach from OP made it seem like that wasn't the goal. Updated either way @BigBen